# Auto-exporting reports in Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

Hi all i'm a system admin just trying to automate some reports that i have to run every morning. I have first locate the report which there are many and then i have to open it feed it the date from yesterday unless it is Monday then i have to use the date from the last working day which is usually Friday. Now i can get the reports to export using the docmd.

But what i can figure out is how to pass it some params

So what i'm thinking that it needs to do is something like this.

```
Dim reportName As String  
Dim fileName As String  
Dim para As String  

reportName = "dailyReports"  
fileName = "C:\reports\report.pdf"  
formanName = ""  
BEGdateVaule = ""  
ENDdateVaule = ""  
para = "Forman = 'formanName' AND BEGdate = 'BEGdateVaule' AND ENDdate = 'ENDdateVaule'"

## if it is Monday then figure out Fridays date

if (weekday(Now()= 2)[  
set date to Fridays  
    for %%x in (  
        formanName = "Tom"  
        formanName = "Dick"  
        formanName = "Harry"   
        )do(  
run Sub  
)  
## if it is tues then figure out mondays date
ect . . 

Sub   
DoCmd.openReport reportName, acViewPreview, para ,acHidden
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, reportName, acFormatPDF, fileName
Docmd.Close acReport, reportName, acSaveno  
end sub
```

So i think i'm on the right track but there are two things that i can figure out;

One: how to get Fridays date/yesterdays date and then set the vars to that.
Two: how to run the code for different formans so each on gets an export of the file by that date.

I'm new to coding but i'm a fast study any direction here would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: Please take a moment to read the site guidelines about asking questions in the [help]. The site rule is one question / Question. There are two good reasons for this 1) No single person may know the answers to multiple question and 2) The site concept is Q&A - it's not a discussion forum. As it stands, this question is "too broad". You can use the [edit] link below the question to change its content so that it complies with the site rules.

Comment: Also, when tagging a question be sure to read the infomation shown when a tag is typed. The tag `access` is ***not*** for Microsoft Access and `macros` are explicitly *not* for coding in Office applications. If you don't tag correctly, the right people won't see the question.

Answer (score 0):

In response to:

> One: how to get Fridays date/yesterdays date and then set the vars to that.

To calculate the date of the previous working day (not accounting for bank holidays), you could use a function such as the following:

```vb
Function LastWorkingDay() As Date
    Dim i As Integer: i = Weekday(Date, vbSaturday)
    If i > 3 Then i = 1
    LastWorkingDay = DateAdd("d", -i, Date)
End Function
```

If the above is evaluated on a Saturday, Sunday or Monday, it will return the date of the previous Friday, else on any other day it will return the previous weekday.

e.g. if run today (`Wednesday 2019-05-15`):

```
?LastWorkingDay
14/05/2019
```

Answer (score 0):

The last work day can be found like this (assuming the code will only run Mon-Fri and not on weekends):

```
LastWorkDay=DateAdd("d",IIF(Weekday(Date)=vbMonday,-3,-1),Date())
```

To run the export for two or more different sets of parameters you have two options:

1. Different export files:

   `DoCmd.openReport reportName, acViewPreview, para_1 ,acHidden 
   DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, reportName, acFormatPDF, filename_1
   Docmd.Close acReport, reportName, acSaveno
   DoCmd.openReport reportName, acViewPreview, para_2 ,acHidden
   DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, reportName, acFormatPDF, filename_2
   Docmd.Close acReport, reportName, acSaveno`
2. Create the report in such a way that each set of parameters is a section that starts on a new page, then set up your parameters to include all sets you want to export. For example:

`para = "Forman IN ('Tom',Dick','Harry') AND BEGdate = 'BEGdateVaule' AND ENDdate = 'ENDdateVaule'"`

This may require re-design of the report(s) that is being exported.

Also, your dates should be actual dates and therefore enclosed in `#` not single quotes.

Comment: Ok is see what your saying instead of trying to run it in a loop if could just plug in the  para and each one has its own number, So then the para var would i change the " BEGdate = #LastWorkDay# And ENDdate = #LastWorkingDay# ?